# How to realize functions in CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have some values (for Example: Name, Salary, Car, home Address) which i need to insert in different entities. After that i need to get it by some value, like with SQL query.
I worked with PostrgeSQL, and made it by functions, how can i make it in coreData?
Can I make any functions in CoreData, or how can I insert values in different entities?
How can I get them after it?

Comment: can u elaborate your requirement? u want to store some data in coreData and u need to retrieve those data right?

Comment: in Class1.m i need to insert values in different entities. in classN.m  i need to get them. I don't know how to insert values in different entities, and how to get values from different entities.

Comment: Just see some demo, how to insert some records in entity and how to fetch..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to core data then you should have to look at some tutorials and also some example demo to create core data, insert data, fetch data, etc.

Following are some links which provide tutorials on core data:-

http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-core-data/
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iPhone_OS_Core_Data_Tutorial